# Is there a way to pull part of a SQL query from a .sql file?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let me simplify with an example. Let's say I have the following query saved on:
`C:\sample.sql`

```
grp.id IN 
(001   --Bob
,002   --Tom
,003   --Fay
)
```

Now, that group of IDs could change, but instead of updating those IDs in every query it's related to, I was hoping to just update in `sample.sql` and the rest of the queries will pull from that SQL file directly.

For example, I have several queries that would have a section like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM GROUP grp
WHERE grp.DATERANGE >= '2017-12-01 AND grp.DATERANGE <= '2017-12-31
AND -- **this is where I would need to insert that query (ie. C:\sample.sql)**
```

**More explained update:**
Issue: I have several reports/queries having the same ID filter (that's the only thing in common between those reports)

What's needed: Instead of updating those IDs every time they change on each report, I was wondering if I can update those IDs in it's own SQL file (like the example above) and have the rest of the queries pull from there.

Note. I can't create a table or database in the used database.

Comment: Put the ids of interest in a table and select from it?  Then you just have to modify the table.

Comment: I can't create tables in the database. I just have read access.

Comment: I'm thinking there is a bigger picture here that you haven't explained. How often do the values change? How often do you run these queries? Where do the values come from?

Comment: Can you create another database? If so `where grp.id IN (select id from otherdatabase.dbo.yourtable)`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I would change these values about once a month. I run it at least once a week. The updated values come from meetings.

Comment: @AlexK. unfortunately, I can't create another database or table

Comment: Bear in mind that SQL Server accepts your query *text* and then acts on that, compiling and transforming it before executing it. All of that activity happens *on the server*, not on your machine. For this to work, the `.sql` file would need to be *on the server*

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that makes sense. So no where to insert a query snippit from my local machine?

Comment: What you're saying here is that you have an arbitrary list that needs to be applied in multiple places to some SQL files, and this list _cannot_ be saved in the database. What you could do is build some template SQL files and just use find and replace. i.e. your sql is `WHERE Field1 IN (<ReplaceMe>)`. Then each time you just find and replace <ReplaceMe> with a tool like FNR.EXE and run the resulting SQL. Is this list stored in say excel? Because you could write some VBA that does all this, runs the SQL and dumps it back in the excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the bulk insert utility could help. Hold your data in csv files and load them into temp tables at run time. Use these temp tables to drive your query.

```
CREATE TABLE #CsvData(
  Column1 VARCHAR(40),
  Column2 VARCHAR(40)
)
GO

BULK
INSERT #CsvData
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO

--Use #CsvData to drive your query
SELECT *
FROM #CsvData
```

Comment: You don't require special permissions to create a temporary table. If you can connect to the server you should be able to create a temp table.

Comment: I didn't realize it was a temporary table. Haven't tried that before. Instead of `FROM #CsvData` you think that could work for `AND#CsvData`? If so, I'll give it a try when I get back online

Comment: if that worked for you can you mark the question as answered. thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe what you could use is a CTE (Common Table Expression) to pull your IDs using an additional query, specially if you only have read access. It would look something like this:

```
WITH myIDs AS (select IDs from grp where (conditions to get the IDs))

SELECT *
FROM grp
WHERE grp.DATERANGE BETWEEN '2017-12-01 AND '2017-12-31'
AND IDs in (select * from myIDs)
```

I've changed the dates syntax to use BETWEEN since it's more practical but only works if you have a SQL Server 2008 or later

Hope this helps!
Cheers!

Comment: The cte is just syntactical sugar here. You could place the same statement within the IN-clause... Or do I miss something? Btw: Your advise concerning `BETWEEN` is dangerous. If the underlying data type is `DATETIME` you'd miss all entries of the final date which have a time portion. [Read this: Aaron Bertrand - bad habits to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: Thanks! A CTE would require an edit to each query that's pulling from this value. I have several reports that need to filter on these IDs

Answer (score 0):

The only chance to *build* a query out of text fragments is dynamic SQL:

Try this:

```
DECLARE @SomeCommand VARCHAR(MAX)='SELECT * FROM sys.objects';
EXEC(@SomeCommand);
```

Returns a list of all sys.object entries

Now I append a `WHERE` clause to the string

```
SET @SomeCommand=@SomeCommand + ' WHERE object_id IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)';
EXEC(@SomeCommand);
```

And you get a reduced result.

Another option is *dynamic IN-list* with a CSV paramter.

This is forbidden: `DECLARE @idList VARCHAR(100)='1,2,3,4'` and use it like `IN (@idList)`.
But this works:

```
DECLARE @idList VARCHAR(100)='1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9';

SELECT sys.objects.*
FROM sys.objects 

--use REPLACE to transform the list to <x>1</x><x>2</x>...
OUTER APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@idList,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS A(ListSplitted)

--Now use the XML (the former CSV) within your IN() as set-based filter
WHERE @idList IS NULL OR LEN(@idList)=0 OR object_id IN(SELECT B.v.value('.','int') FROM ListSplitted.nodes('/x') AS B(v));
```

With a version of SQL Server 2016+ this can be done much easier using `STRING_SPLIT()`.

This approach allows you to pass the id-list as simple text parameter.

Comment: This looks advanced. Just to confirm, I have several reports using the same filter for IDs. Instead of updating each query when those IDs change, I was wondering if I can have a SQL file with that bit of the query updated, and have the rest of the queries pull the updated list from there.

Comment: @kazzi Don't know exactly what you are talking about... Did you consider to build a *wrapping* query around your existing query...? `SELECT qry.* FROM (YourExistingQueryHere) AS qry WHERE id IN(SomeList)`?